# Radio Button Search Combine Two Parameters C# Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

Looking for some help on doing a combined search for a name like John Smith.  I can get the search to work for either John or Smith but when I combine the two I get no results back.

Controller - Only brings back first or last name (as expected with ||)

```
public ActionResult index(string searchBy, string search)
    {
     if (searchBy == "name")
        { return View(db.members.Where(x => x.members_firstname.Contains(search) 
                       || x.members_lastname.Contains(search)).ToList());
    }
```

Controller - Does not work

```
public ActionResult index(string searchBy, string search)
    {
     if (searchBy == "name")
        { return View(db.members.Where(x => x.members_firstname.Contains(search) 
                       && x.members_lastname.Contains(search)).ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
<p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Members", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <b>Search By</b><@Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "name", true)<text>Name</text>
        @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "members_id") <text> ID</text>
        @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="search" />
    }
</p>
```

Member Model

```
  public string members_firstname { get; set; }
    public string members_lastname { get; set; }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you are using one search string to find first name and last name so you will be able to find only members like John John or Smith Smith. You need to add second parameter for last name to the index action and modify the view to handle two parameters:

```
public ActionResult index(string searchBy, string searchFirstName, string searchLastName)
{
    if (searchBy == "name")
    { 
        return View(db.members.Where(x => x.members_firstname.Contains(searchFirstName) 
                                       && x.members_lastname.Contains(searchLastName)).ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. How would I go about the view form.  Can I pass searchFirstName and searchLastName in one textbox (if so what would that look like)?  Or would they need their own textbox?

Comment: You can add another option to search by first name and last name and use javascript to show second textbox for last name when the option is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your help - Jay